# Which is natural?

Tags: grammaticality

1. Mary is more talkative than any other girl/girls in the class.
2. Mary is a more talkative girl than any other girl/girls in the class.

I'd like to know which is natural. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions are natural, but **more than any** needs a singular complement.

Mary is more talkative than other **girls**.

Mary is more talkative than **any** other **girl**.

**Any** refers randomly and individually to a member of a set.

Imagine the *ordered* set of odd positive numbers between 1 and 11:

{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}

**All** member**s** of the set **are** odd.

Loop
{
Run a random-number generator to get an integer between 1 and 6, *n*.
The *n*th member of the set of odd numbers is odd.
}
Repeat

**Any** member of that set of odd numbers **is** odd.